# Can java flag missing JAR references on the classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

This is a case of the `CLASSPATH` pointing to a JAR that does not exist with no indication from the JRE.

Over the years, there have been a few occasions where a JAR file that includes the version number in the filename (e.g. jasperreports-5.6.0.jar) has been updated to a new version (e.g. jasperreports-6.3.0.jar), and subsequently and I've missed updating the class path in some location to point to the new JAR.  This could happen either when there is an old reference in the `CLASSPATH` variable or when the `MANIFEST.MF` of another JAR file hasn't had its `Class-Path` entry updated.  Then when running the application, I get no error about the JAR file being missing until I go to use the reporting functionality.

Ideally, it would be nice if the `ClassLoader` would let me know what is missing on my class path.  Is there some kind of flag to the Java runtime?

I'm guessing that the answer is that there is nothing and I'd have to maybe write/subclass my own `ClassLoader`, but maybe someone knows something I couldn't find.  If this doesn't exist, will this functionality be provided in Java 9's Jigsaw feature?

Comment: You'd be better off using a tool that eliminates such mistakes for you, such as an IDE with Maven support.

Comment: Better living through automation!  Good point, @EJP.  Unfortunately, I haven't yet tried to change my ant-based build over to Maven.  I'm still hoping there is a run-time option to report the relevant error.